# Getting redux-form error when I import Modal from native-base instead of react-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, redux-form, native-base

I have the following code in my React Native app:

```
class ModalComponent extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Modal visible={this.props.visible}>
                <View>
                  <View>
                    <Field/>
                  </View>
                  <View>
                    <Field/>
                  </View>
                  <View>
                    <Field/>
                  </View>
                </View>
            </Modal>             
        );
    }
}

ModalComponent =  reduxForm({
    form: 'modalComponentForm'
})(ModalComponent)
export default connect(mapStateToProps, bindAction)(ModalComponent);
```

Previously I was importing `Modal` from `react-native` and it worked fine, but now I'm importing it from `native-base` and it throws the error `Field must be inside a component decorated with reduxForm()`.

In other posts with this error, it was just a matter of wrapping the component in `reduxForm()` the way I've done here.

Does anyone know what could be causing this error?